# Beamer - transition effect

Tags: beamer

I am looking for a particular transition effect when moving between slides.
I would like to have the impression that two slides are superimposed and that the first moves smoothly to the right to reveal progressively the next slide.
Any idea?

Comment: maybe not directly in beamer, but try impressive http://impressive.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Martin H: Thank you for the recommendation. I will have a look at it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

PDF offers a standardized way for transitions and these work in also in Beamer Latex. You can use them in Latex between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` and they should work
with common PDF viewers.

```
                  Show the slide as if horizontal blinds were pulled away.
\transblindshorizontal

                   Show the slide as if vertical blinds were pulled away.
\transblindsvertical

                   Show the slide by moving to the center from all four sides.
       \transboxin

                   Show the slide by showing more and more of a rectangular area that is centered on the slide center
      \transboxout

                   Slowly dissolve what was shown before
\transdissolve

                   Glitter sweeps in specified direction
\transglitter

                   Show the slide by sweeping two vertical lines from the sides inward.
\transsplitverticalin

                   Show the slide by sweeping two vertical lines from the center outward.
\transsplitverticalout

                   Show the slide by sweeping two horizontal lines from the sides inward.
\transsplithorizontalin

                   Show the slide by sweeping two horizontal lines from the center outward.
\transsplithorizontalout

                   Sweeps single line in specified direction
\transwipe

                   Show slide specified number of seconds
\transduration{2}
                   Show the slide by pushing what was shown before off the screen using the new content.
\transpush
                   Replace the previous slide directly (default behaviour).
\transreplace
                   Show the slide by covering the content that was shown before
\transcover
```

Comment: There are some more transition effects, introduced in PDF 1.5: `\transcover`, `\transfade`, `\transpush`, `\transuncover`. These are already implemented in `beamer`, but [not yet documented](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/165/pdf-newer-transitions-not-documented).

Comment: What about moving text (instead of the transition of the whole page)?

Comment: Is there a way to apply transitions also at overlays?

Comment: @barbaz: yes, the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) is clear about that. Overlay specifications can be applied to transitions the usual way (i.e., with `<>`).

Comment: I used this and put things like <1> and <2>. Why won't these work?