# How to use effects on beamer [Lyx user]

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am trying to use Beamer in Lyx in order to write my thesis presentation and i would like to add some effects in it (for e.x. fade away etc)..

How can i add effects in Lyx while using beamer?

Comment: I would suggest that transitions are unnecessary for a thesis presentation, but you can try adding the commands seen [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23136/586) in an ERT between frames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beamer - transition effect](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22412/beamer-transition-effect)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to commented [transitions between frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22412), Beamer can do many several effects within frames with commands `\pause`, `\only`, `\visible` `\uncover` or `\onslide`, that have overlays specifications that can be also applied to normal LaTeX \items of enumerate or itemize environments for example, or at the whole environments.

A transition within a frame is obtained generating a new slide, so have in mind that the abuse of these effects can slow down significantly your talk and boring your audience if there are not time constrains.But a judicious combinations of overlays with `\alert` or `\spot` (need package of the same name) could be very effective.

The following MWE is only a frame the produce 3 slides showing some of these effects.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\begin{frame}{Only a frame, slide \thepage}

Normal text \alert<1-3>{ 1}\alert<2-3>{ 2}\alert<3>{ 3}

\only<1>{First only} 
\only<2>{Second only}
\only<3>{Third only}

\visible<1>{First visible}
\visible<2>{Second visible}
\visible<3>{Third visible}

\uncover<1-3>{First uncover}
\uncover<2-3>{Second uncover}
\uncover<3>{Third uncover}

\begin{enumerate}
\item<1|alert@1> First enumerate
\item<2> Second enumerate
\item<3> Third enumerate
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
        \item item
        \item item
        \item item
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Tip: make `texdoc beamer`. Go to page 78.